# Execute service or script via hotkey

Tags: raspbian-stretch, keyboard, terminal, raspbian-lite

I use Raspbian lite.
I'm trying to map a hotkey to start the service or a script. I do not use a graphical user interface, only a text console with a local attached display. I'm not using ssh.

I tried using `xbindkeys`, but:

```
> xbindkeys -k
Could not open display, check shell DISPLAY variable, and export or setenv it!
```

How can I map a key to start a script?

Comment: Hi Pasha, Is this from a console/terminal, headless via ssh, or have you installed a gui on the Pi?

Comment: Hi Danny! No gui, only console/terminal, locally without ssh.

Answer (score 1):

You do not use a graphical user interface (GUI) so I guess you are using *Raspbian Stretch Lite*. With a default installation of it there is no `xbindkeys` installed for good reasons. With `apt show xbindkeys` you will find:

> xbindkeys is a program that allows you to launch shell commands with
>    your keyboard or your mouse under the X Window System.

The X Window System is the default GUI on Linux so it is unsurprising that *xbindkeys* complains it cannot find a DISPLAY for graphical output.

On the default bash shell you can use the builtin command `bind`. Look for help with `help bind`. I have found an answer at [How to execute a script in shell when a shortcut key is pressed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89624/243074).

Comment: I tried BIND. He can not bind a button. Power button . maybe there are other ways?

Comment: @PashaGeronimo So far we only talked about keyboard keys as guessed when you talk about hotkey and *xbindkeys*. The power button is not a keyboard key so neither *xbindkeys* nor *bind* can manage it. What are you trying to do with the power button? Running a script before shutdown?

Comment: Ingo, i use this remote [link](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/Black-Controle-Remoto-FM4-2-4GHz-Wireless-Keyboard-Remote-Control-Air-Mouse-For-Android-KODI-TV/32582575969.html) . It work like as keyboard. When i press Power nothing happens (linux not shutdown). I need to map Power some script to button Power.