# Remapping a key on a keyboard as dedicated shutdown button

Tags: shutdown

I have a RP4 and want to remap a button from my keyboard to be a dedicated shutdown button.
I don't really want to add an external shutdown/power switch to it since my power supply unit has a power switch.

The Keyboard is a Logitech K400 plus with european/german keymapping and I am an absolut beginner with coding, the Pi and anything regarded to it. So please have patience with me ^^

I searched through various similar threads here, but did not find one, that is about this specific topic. So if there is already one and I have overseen this, please excuse me for that and post the link.

With best regards
Siggi

Comment: does [this](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/raspberry-pi-custom-keyboard-shortcuts,40215.html) help at all

Comment: or [this question on stack exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90486/execute-service-or-script-via-hotkey)

Comment: first one looks pretty good to me, I will try it and give feedback on it
thank you very much for this quick answer

Comment: I followed everything in the first link and prepared what I would type in
but when I wrote sudo nano etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml it said that "etc/xdg/openbox does not exist"

the command for the keybinding would have been:

<keybind key="C-A-p"><action name="Execute"><command>sudo poweroff</command></action></keybind>
or instead of "C-A-p" "0x1008ff2f" which is fn+Ins (the keyboard standby button)
is at least this command correct?
but I really dont know why sudo nano etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml did not work
do I need to create/prepare it for the first link?

Comment: btw this is what I installed as OS
https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/
just this and nothing else

Comment: oh, NOOBS .. can't do it in noobs

Comment: someone else told me I forgot the first "/" in "sudo nano /etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml

I followed his advice and the window popped up just like in the first link yours and followed the steps accordingly and entered

<keybind key="C-A-p"><action name="Execute"><command> sudo poweroff</command></action></keybind>

and it works :D
thank you for your contribution <3

Comment: Please don't use comments for details. They are unreadable because they are not made for this. Instead [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/113738/edit) your question and add it there.